# Pythonic way to deal with index -0

Tags: python, indexing

I have the following output from a Keras net:

```
batch_cut_train = training_set_size - Y_train.shape[0]
batch_cut_test = abs(training_set_size - Y.shape[0]) - Y_test.shape[0]

first_output = model.predict(X_test, batch_size=batch_size)

output = pd.DataFrame(first_output, index=features[-Y_test.shape[0]-batch_cut_test:-batch_cut_test].index, columns=labels.columns)
```

When I my data is exactly divisible by the batch_size, I get batch_cut_train = 0. Then, when I index it into features, I get

```
features[:-0]
```

which throws an error. What would be a clean way to avoid this?

The error is `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (6, 1696), indices imply (6, 0)` because it's indexing into 0 so the range shown in features (a pd.DataFrame) is empty basically.

EDIT: This fixes it but may not be the nicest way to do so:

```
batch_cut_train = training_set_size - Y_train.shape[0]
batch_cut_test = abs(training_set_size - Y.shape[0]) - Y_test.shape[0]


first_output = model.predict(X_test, batch_size=batch_size)

if batch_cut_test != 0:
    output = pd.DataFrame(first_output, index=features[-Y_test.shape[0]-batch_cut_test:-batch_cut_test].index, columns=labels.columns)
else:
    output = pd.DataFrame(first_output, index=features[-Y_test.shape[0]:].index, columns=labels.columns)

o = output.join(df['PX LAST'])
o.tail()
```

Comment: `-0` will be directly evaluated to `0`. In any case "an error" is the worst type of error since nobody can help you with it. Please post the full error traceback!

Comment: what is `features`? is it a `list`? `-0 == 0` so I suspect you are doing somethig wrong

Comment: What kind of object is `features`? If it is a list, `features[:-0]` should be the same as `features[:0]`, which in turn yields an empty list. What error does it throw for you?

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is something like `-(batch_cut_test+1)`
Saying this because in the negative index, values start from 1 and not 0.

Comment: Negative zero isn't really a thing (it exists in archaic one's complement computers and floats, but not as indices). I'm rather confused why your snippet appears to be trying to use exclusively negative indexing. 

The clean way to fix this is to build a clear model of what sort of chunk you're trying to work with, out of which you can generate actual ranges. I can't do it for you as I got quite lost with your at least 4 different input arrays, where you don't appear to know which of training_set_size and Y.shape[0] is larger, but somehow don't care.